# Why can't we use magnets to create energy like this?

Tags: magnetics, energy, magnet

Won't it rotate continuously?

Why can't this happen? Energy cannot be created, right?

Then will the magnets degrade over time and stop being magnets?

But they don't have their own energy also.

Then how?

[image]

Comment: You can't create energy, that's right. But I also don't see where you're doing that, or why this should continously rotate? If you *removed* all magnets, yes, then this thing would rotate for eternity, due to conservation of impulse / energy. With the magnets, it will halt pretty soon.

Comment: Magnets don't create energy. They CAN convert it from electric energy to mechanical, and vice versa. So you can put work into spinning those moving magnets, and generate electricity in a coil ... or put electricity in a coil and (with the right timings) it'll move those magnets.

Comment: Look for Perendev machine. It can work just enough time to demonstrate and collect money, but the inventor is jailed.

Comment: All magnets demagnetize over time. The magnet's own magnetic field is trying to demagnetize itself.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how that drawing is supposed to work. VTC unclear from me.

Comment: `Then how?` ...   what is this question asking?

Comment: Is that another try to create perpertum mobile?

Comment: It will work for a quarter of a rotation, maybe, if you remove the glue and anchor the bar magnet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It won't rotate forever.  If you build one, you will notice that it takes force to make the moving magnets pass the fixed magnets.

You have to push the moving N towards the fixed N - like poles push each other away.

You have to push the moving N away from the fixed S as the moving magnet passes the fixed one.

If you try it, you will see the moving magnets slow as they get closer to the fixed magnets.  You will also see the moving magnets slow as they go away from the fixed magnets.

To make it worse, the material of the magnets is itself magnetic.  The material of all magnets is attracted to the field of other magnets - regardless of the pole. You can stick a weak magnet N pole to the N pole of a strong magnet because the attraction of the strong magnet to the material of the weak magnet is stronger than the repulsion between the N pole of the weak magnet and the N pole of the strong magnet.

Your "perpetual motion" machine will stop after just a few rotations with the moving magnets "stuck" near the fixed magnets.

---

This is not a new idea - you are not the first person to have this idea or fall into this trap.

The idea is common enough that it has its own [wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_motor)

Answer (score 2):

The way it's drawn, if you rotate clockwise around 120 degrees, you will have a North pole on the rotor next to a South on the static magnet, and the South on the rotor next to the North on the static magnet.

At that point, it has no reason to move anywhere.  You would have to apply a force to pull them apart.

Answer (score 1):

> Won't it rotate continuously?

> Why can't this happen? Energy cannot be created, right?

Right. Anything that rotates on earth has forces acting on it that will stop it eventually unless energy is used to overcome friction and aerodynamic drag. It is possible to reduce friction and drag to very low values, but not eliminate them completely.

> Then will the magnets degrade over time and stop being magnets?

Magnets can last for a very long time. Degradation would mostly be oxidation etc. There are natural magnets that have existed since the earth was formed. Magnets can be used in ways that would demagnetize them, but many will remain useful until they fall apart from chemical degradation etc.

> But they don't have their own energy also.

Yes.

> Then how?

Magnets have energy somewhat similar to the energy of a compressed spring. Look at answers to this question:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69400/does-a-magnet-contain-and-potentially-produce-energy

Answer (score -7):

still its fashinating to see if magnets can be used to find a way to get free electricity in return.

You would expect its possible, the way a magnet can pull things towards itself but also away should make it possible to make a tick tock clock, where each tick and tock you get a little energy in return by the movement of the part that you using.
Like a dynamo of a bike.

For example if you have a closed plastic tube with a magnet at both sides, and a metal ball in between it, where the tube is sitting at a seesaw.
Below each end of the tube you put a magnet that points upwards to pull things away from itself.
So that if the ball comes at one end of the tube, the gravity makes the seesaw fall down to that side, but the magnet below it forces that side to come up again, and the magnet inside the tube pushes the ball at that same time away from itself, so that the metal ball should go all the way to the otherside, and there the same happens.
Each time the metal ball is moving, you could get some eletricity in return.

But to be fair, to make power wind turbines/mills run not by wind but by magnets, how large those magnets should be, and howmuch force you have to apply, and howmuch energy you have to put into magnets in the first place.
And isnt there a law of Einstein that you never get more energy in return as what you put into it.

Even if we make very tiny scaled seesaw's of like ten thousands that all moving by magnets.

In theory you would think it would be possible to make a never ending loop of a moving part, but in the real world it doesnt always work as we hope.

would be great if every house has a special room with magnets that spinning a wheel, and that wheel generates energy like a dynamo.
Prolly not if you using a pacemaker.

Comment: No. It is not a matter of getting large enough magnets or of practicality. It is just 'no'.